# Create user-defined table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

What I want, is creating a table using HTML and JS.

The first line is the header of the table which shall be set in advance.
The number of rows in the table should be entered at the top of the HTML Document (before the table is created, that is).

What I am struggeling with is the transportation of the variable "nr" (number of rows) into the JS function (tried testing with alert).

Also, if someone has a good idea how to actually create the table it'd be much apreciated.

---

This is what I've got so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> The Hausarbeit</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function makeTable() {
                /*r=document.getElementById("zeilen").value;
                var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
                for(i=1;i<=parseInt(r);i++){
                var row=table.insertRow(i);
                var y=r.insertCell(0);
                    y.innerHtml=i.value;*/
                var zeilen;
                zeilen = document.getElementById("zeilen").value;
                alert('zeilen.value');
            }

            function random() {

            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            table,
            td {
                border: 2px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> Anzahl der Arbeitspakete=
            <input type="text" id="zeilen" /input>
            <input type="button" value="Tabelle erstellen" onClick="makeTable()" /input>
            <input type="button" value="Test Werte" onClick="random" /input>
        </div>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
                <td>Dauer</td>
                <td>Vorg&auml;nger</td>
                <td>FAZ</td>
                <td>FEZ</td>
                <td>SAZ</td>
                <td>SEZ</td>
                <td>Puffer</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, the number of columns is supposed to be 8 per row, the first 3 cells of every row are supposed to be changeable, so one is able to let another script calculate and display a critical path analysis with that table.

Any help would be much appreciated, since this is homework due at Apr.11th.
Thanks a lot in advance!

UPDATE:
Since it seems I didn't specify my question/Problem clearly enough, I'm adding some pseudocode to the question :

```
User input: number of rows>>n;
Button onClick: js creates table: n rows, 8 columns; couple of strings for table header;
First column: count 1 to n;
2nd column: cells editable by user>>duration;
3rd column: cells editable by user>>required_packages (separated by ",") 

using the given information (duration and required packages) the below values shall be calculated and filled into the table by pressing a button at the bottom
(one package can depend on more than one package, dependencies work recursively
[e.g. 2 depends on 1, 3 depends on 2, so 3 depends on 1 recursively]) 

4th column: FAZ (earliest time the work package can be started) 
5th column: FEZ (earliest time the work package can be finished) 
6th column: SAZ (latest time the work package can be started)
7th column: SEZ (latest time the work package can be finished) 
//note to 6 and 7: without the entire project getting delayed (dependencies) 
8th column: time difference between 6th and 7th column  (alternatively 4th and 5th column, doesn't matter since difference is the same)
```

Hope that helped you helping me! 
Again, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Your code have an additional `}` check it.

Comment: `alert('zeilen.value');` is just going to give you the string `zeilen.value` literaly, try `alert(zeilen);` since you assigned the input value to that variable

Comment: and rather go for console.log for testing, alert will be too annoying after a while!

Comment: @AntonHarald I was going to mention that but i thought baby steps might be in order here :)

Comment: Thanks for being an error log guys! c: could that result in the script not working? Since even the alert didn't alert as it was supposed to, not even the string...

Answer (score 0):

To create the table, you could use something like the following (passing in rows and columns from your form/fields);

```
// HTML
<input id='rows'>
<input id='columns'>
<button id='makeTable'>Make Table</button>

// JAVASCRIPT
function makeTable(rows, columns){
  var table = document.createElement('table');

  for(var x = 0; x < rows; x++){
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for(var y = 0; y < columns; y++){
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.innerHTML =  'Text' + y;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    table.appendChild(tr);
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

var button = document.getElementById('makeTable').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  var columns = document.getElementById('columns').value;

  makeTable(rows, columns);
})
```

### Update

Fixed Code & JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/th6c445x/2/

Comment: table.appendChild('tr') >> table.appendChild(tr);

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```js
var element = {
    zeilen : document.getElementById("zeilen"),
    table : document.getElementById("myTable"),
    makeTable : document.getElementById("makeTable"),
    random : document.getElementById("random"),
};

var generate = function() {
    element.table.innerHTML = '';
    var zeilen = parseInt(element.zeilen.value);
    for(var i = 0; i < zeilen; i++) {
        var row = element.table.insertRow(i);
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = (i + 1) + ', ' + (j + 1);
        }
    }
}

element.makeTable.addEventListener('click', generate);

element.random.addEventListener('click', function makeTable() {
    element.zeilen.value = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    generate();
});
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div> Anzahl der Arbeitspakete=
    <input id="zeilen" type="text" />
    <input id="makeTable" type="button" value="Tabelle erstellen" />
    <input id="random" type="button" value="Test Werte" />
</div>
<table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <td>T&auml;tigkeit</td>
              <td>Dauer</td>
              <td>Vorg&auml;nger</td>
              <td>FAZ</td>
              <td>FEZ</td>
              <td>SAZ</td>
              <td>SEZ</td>
              <td>Puffer</td>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myTable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qqjrLe2f/7/))

Comment: Almost! It's like I want to set the number of work packages (Arbeitspakete) first, then edit the 2nd and 3rd cell of every row setting the duration of the package (German: Dauer) and the work packages required completed (German: Vorgänger). The first line is just straight numbers 1-n. And then I need a second button on the bottom (outside the table) to have JS calculate the other values for me. Like FAZ is "Früheste Anfangszeit" which means the time all other packages one package is depending on are done.

Comment: @Steve : Could you give me some sample data for what should be put in your table when eg. the user fills in a value of 5?

Comment: When the user puts in 5, the table should have 3 rows. The first column should have the numbers 1 to 5 in them and all other cells are empty. Then, the user should be able to edit all cells in the 2nd and 3rd row, applying duration and required packages (the numbers for the other packages). Then, with the button at the bottom the other cells are supposed to be calculated by js (I think I can make up some pseudo source code and post it later) so gimme 2 hrs and I'll upload a sample and the pseudo code.

Comment: @Steve : I'll look into it when you provided the pseudo-code... not sure I'll be able to do that today, though. I have a social life to attend to ;-)

Comment: Pseudo-code provided (see the original question, hope that clarified things! Thank you a lot for sacrificing your free time for me! ;D

Comment: @Steve : I think I understand your pseudo-code, but I'm still missing test data. You're talking about work packages that have four dates + dependencies. In what format are those dates stored? How are those dependencies stored? Give us some test data to work with if you want us to help you with that!

Comment: Well, the assignment is about project management, so the work packages are not digital but analog things which have to be done first. Look at it like building a house: the planning would be package 1, the base of the house package 2, the walls are package 3 ect.

Comment: @Steve : That information has to be stored somewhere... at some time... in some format... Just give me some sample / demo data to work with. Or are you saying it has to be filled in manually AFTER the table is generated?

Comment: Exactly, the table is generated with the given rows, one fills in the data into 2nd and 3rd column in every row (for every package there may be different values) and another button calculates the other values from the values in the table. So it's: enter row count> table creation>fill in values>calculate other calues